What other terms have been used to describe storing working data permanently besides "save"?
Today, we "save" the file we're working on to disk. This terminology appears to be specific to architectures combining volatile and non-volatile memory. I also distinctly remember a "load/store" naming scheme from my youth, and "commit" from times well before git.
By what other names has this operation been known historically? Was similar functionality (logically committing the changes) called differently in machines without volatile memory?
(Note: there is a similar question related to this here - When did the floppy disk icon become the standard symbol for the “save” function in user interfaces? - but my question is about how it came to be called the save function and what other names it had.)

CTSS had SAVE in the (to me) common sense of writing a core image from the current content of the user's core. So as far as interactive systems are concerned, I'd say SAVE has always existed under that name. The use for writing out the data that a program is currently working on seems like an obvious extension to the use of the word.

I think your distinction between volatile and non-volatile memory misses the mark. The distinction (at least on systems with drums and disks) is between program 'operational' memory and file systems. A file system is where you expect your data to still be there tomorrow, long after your program ended. Not all non-volatile memory was arranged into a file system.

In some cases there was no command. You simply turned on the paper tape punch on your ASR-33 and then listed out, or ran, your program. That the system used core memory was irrelevant.

On systems where data was saved on paper tape or punchards, did any use "PUNCH" as the command?

Maybe it's just me, but IMO, "Save," and "store," and "commit," mean three different things; "Save" is something you do with a work space, "store" is something your program does with data, and "commit" is one possible end point for a transaction. Of course you might argue that, a workspace is data for some programs. But then I would argue that you are mixing levels of abstraction. In my mind, when the user wants to save their workspace, the IDE stores the data that represent that workspace, probably by performing a sequence of writes to one or more files.

The only one that matters legally: archive. That's the 'copy' you can legally make of a copyrighted work of which you have leased the copyright. Not to be confused with reproduction. Neither of which are to be distributed.

@Barmar - several, for example, TOPS-10,  After all, using PUNCH to punch seems as obvious as using PRINT to print.  Whether PUNCH was for cards or tape was either a matter of system heritage or (as on TOPS-10) local convention.

"Stash" - a la git. Though I offer this frivolously, it does have the sense of "save where I am at so I can come back to it later".

There is a discussion regarding the etymology of Save at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46154/why-we-say-save-file-and-not-keep-preserve-file

@MarkWilliams Thanks, that adds some references to consider. I still think RC.se is more qualified to figure this out )

read and write are the normal terms used by programmers to send or retrieve data to a stream which may or may not exist on non-volatile storage, along with open, close etc...
SAVE certainly goes back to BASIC in the 60s, and probably before!
For example, WordStar 1.0 (1978) used ctrl-KS to Save the current file, but ctrl-KW to Write the currently selected block of text to a file.
Similarly, the vi text editor for Unix (1976) used :w as a command to write the current file. This followed the ed line editor (1969) which also used w to write the memory buffer to a file. In both cases write referred to the action of copying all the text in the volatile memory to non-volatile storage.
This historical terminology still occurs in modern software. For example Blender 3D still references:

CTRL-W. Write file. This key combination allows you to write the
Blender file without opening a FileWindow.

As noted in the comments, software such as "Expensive Typewriter" for the PDP-1 (1972) used P to 'punch' the current buffer to tape.

In my experience, 'save' is applied at a different level than 'write'.  A save likely requires many writes.

@Dave, I've added an example of how both were used, though not interchangeably.

IMO, "read" and "write" are the names of lower-level abstractions than "load" and "store." "Load" and "store" describe what you want to do with some data. "Read and "write" operations are how the program does it.

@Solomonslow sure, that's your interpretation of the question. It says "By what other names has this operation been known historically?" "This operation" could refer to the operation by the user, or by the program.

@Dave, quite. A read or write is a typical single base-level data transfer whereas 'Save' is a file system operation. The OP writes "Today, we "save" the file we're working on to disk" so we're looking at this file system operation, later asking "By what other names has this operation been known". The 'Save' operation has established itself in Windows/Mac terminology for 40 yrs with no change. Over computing's lifetime, what was done in early software/editors/etc is a bit dwarfed by 40year of user Saves in MS Word/Excel/etc. I don't see the question as about simply putting data on a disk.

@TonyM good point, but before it was so established, programmers had to make choices about what terminology to use. Both Save and Write were used by programmers first, and I've shown that both were still used in applications in the 1970s. The question asks for 'historical' use, so the established conventions of the last 40 years are not at issue.

I deleted my comment put on your original 3-line answer - it became irrelevant when you'd edited it 9 times to make a very different answer 4x longer :-) (original answer was just "read and write are the normal ones for programmers to send or retrieve data to a stream which may or may not exist on non-volatile storage, along with open, close etc... SAVE certainly goes back to BASIC in the 60s, and probably before!") As said, that first answer was just about rd/wr whereas Save is quite different, hence my comments on it Your now-heavily revised answer does actually address the question!

Thanks @TonyM. I believe that the purpose of comments is to improve the answer, and I welcomed your input. The point of the original answer was that programmers would originally have used save or write and as they wrote the applications, either could have been adopted for users. The rest of the answer was only to add examples of how some applications adopted write as well. This was in response to your contribution.

Pleasure doing business, attitudes like yours do the site no end of good, quite honestly :-) My policy is: take what's useful from my comments, discard what isn't. Glad there was something useful in there, the answer reads well now and I'd upvoted. Have a great day.

The IBM 1130 Disk Utility Program used "STORE". To store a freshly compiled binary from Working Storage to the User Area under the name "PROG1", you'd do:
// DUP
*STORE      WS  UA  PROG1

It was crucial to put in exactly the correct amount of white space.

"White space?" If I was to guess, I'd guess that  those two lines were card images. Cards don't got "whitespace." Cards have columns. I'd guess that it was crucial to put the different parts of that command in the proper columns.

Unpunched columns are white unless you're using colored cards ツ

I've never seen a white punch card. They were mostly a sort of cream colour.  I propose 'creamspace' as the appropriate term for unpunched columns. Often, creamspace was printed as greenspace.

Reading through documentation for Univac machines there seems to be a move from store to save as you go from the 50s to the 70s.
